# Unable to resolve custom label in lightning web component

Tags: lightning-web-components

With reference to the document [Access Labels](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.create_labels) for lwc, I created few custom labels and used them in my web component; most of the labels were unable to resolve. I don't understand why exactly.

To simulate the behaviour, created 2 labels as `FirstTest` and `SecondTest` and a simple lwc as follows:

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

import FirstTest from '@salesforce/label/c.FirstTest';
import SecondTest from '@salesforce/label/c.SecondTest';

export default class customLabelCheck extends LightningElement {

    // init method
    connectedCallback() {
        const myLabel = {
            FirstTest,
            SecondTest
        }
        console.log("label", JSON.stringify(myLabel));
    }

    // Expose the labels to use in the template.
    label = {
        FirstTest,
        SecondTest
    };
}
```

On load the console output is as:

> label {"FirstTest":"$Label.rdev.FirstTest does not exist.","SecondTest":"$Label.rdev.SecondTest does not exist."}

I am testing this in my scratch org with a namespace as `rdev`. Don't think we have to do any additional thing to resolve the labels?

Comment: Do you get the values on your HTML when you access the `label` property?

Comment: While accessing the values in HTML, I get the same value as in `console.log`'s.

Comment: Have you tried with the namespace? As `rdev.FirstTest` in the import statement? The docs mentions -- *The name of the label in your org in the format `namespace.labelName`*

Comment: Yes, I did try `import FirstTest from '@salesforce/label/rdev.FirstTest';` which gives compile time error in vscode as: `Invalid module id "rdev.FirstTest" for type "label". Explicit use of namespace "rdev" in file "customLabelCheck.js" is prohibited. Use default namespace "c" instead.`

Comment: I did try it in a namespace vs. non-namespace org and it works fine using `c.labelName`. I am sure the labels exist else you would have got a compile time error but may be worth taking a look as it suggests in the logs?

Comment: Verified that labels exists and thanks for tsking time to verify, let me try the same in scratch orgs from different namespace. Will get back.

Comment: Hey @Raul, were you ever able to get this resolved? If so, what was your solution?

Comment: @Charles don't know anymore as I changed my job, thought this to be a bug as same code worked on our integration sandbox but not on our scratch orgs. Good luck!